# terraform create remote file with content

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to let terraform create an file on the remote system with a specific content, but so far I'm not able to do it.

My code:

```
    provider "vsphere" {
      alias = "main"
    }
    
    resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
...
 dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = var.data_disks
    content {
      label             = "disk${disk.value["lun"]}"
      size              = disk.value["disk_size_gb"]
      unit_number       = disk.value["lun"]
      storage_policy_id = var.vsphere_storage_policy_id
      eagerly_scrub     = var.eagerly_scrub
      thin_provisioned  = var.thin_provisioned
    }


  provisioner "file" {
    content  = "var.data_disks"
    destination = "/tmp/disk.cfg"
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      host        = vsphere_virtual_machine.vm.default_ip_address
      user        = var.admin_user
      private_key = var.admin_private_key
      timeout     = "5m"
    }
  }
```

data_disk looks like this:

```
data_disks             = [
    { "lun": 1,  "disk_size_gb": 4, "filesystem": "xfs", "mountpoint": "/test1", "mountopts": "" },
    { "lun": 2,  "disk_size_gb": 6, "filesystem": "xfs", "mountpoint": "/test2", "mountopts": ""}
]
```

The "content" on the file provisioner is more a placeholder. I want the content to be the whole "data_disk[]" array. Any idea how to manage that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `content = jsonencode(var.data_disks)`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you should probably take a look at: https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.

Answer (score 1):

As frederik mentioned in the comments, this was the solution:

content = jsonencode(var.data_disks)